# What is the difference between SQL servers and SQL managed instances in azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am planning to migrate our Sql server to Azure, so in Azure portal, under "All service", we can see two types of Sql Server service,

- SQL managed instances
- SQL servers

[image]

Under both the types we can create databases. So what is the difference? couldn't find much in google, can somebody shed light on this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure SQL is a PaaS cloud first offering. It is close to what traditional SQL server offers, but its not there yet.

SQL Managed Instances is almost a PaaS, but more like a Managed SQL cluster, not completely abstracted platform you can utilize. In fact Managed SQL cluster is a SQL availability group you can use to host your databases. It is almost identical to on prem SQL servers (minor differences like MSDTC support at this time, and probably some others)

Managed SQL is aimed at legacy apps that cannot be migrated to Azure SQL, but will work in Managed SQL instances.

Reference:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/03/07/what-is-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-2/